# CakePHP 3 ORM : Cache metadata issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm working on a project which only a few packages of cake 3 :

- cakephp/orm
- cakephp/validation
- cakephp/i18n
- cakephp/cache

I just installed the last one (cache).

I uploaded my project to a production server, and was surprised to see that my queries using the ORM are extremely slow (a query that lasts about 100ms on my local machine can take up to 5 or 10 seconds on the production server).

It seems that there are queries on the *information_schema* table that take much time and resources. So I've went on the web and saw that I needed the enable cacheMetaData param in my config.

My config looks like this :

```
ConnectionManager::config('default', [
    'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
    'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
    'host' => 'my-host',
    'database' => 'my-database',
    'username' => 'my-username',
    'password' => 'my-password',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'cacheMetaData' => true // If set to `true` you need to install the optional "cakephp/cache" package.
]);
```

I followed the instruction above and installed the *cakephp/cache* package. But I'm guessing I need to enable it somehow (or somewhere), but can't figure out how (or where).

Here is what I tried :

```
\Cake\Cache\Cache::config('_cake_model_', [
     'className' => 'File',
     'prefix' => 'myapp_cake_model_',
     'path' => '/cache/models/',
     'serialize' => true,
     'duration' => '+2 minutes',
]);
```

But it's still not working, my *cache* or *cache/models/* folder is still empty and the requests are taking a long time.

How can I fix this ?

Thanks for your time

kinkaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a detailed solution on this topic, please see http://discourse.cakephp.org/t/orm-cache-metadata-issue/1071